# Composer autoloader seems to be not included correctly

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to implement simple library without web server. That means I actually don't have any entry point where I can include autoload.php. 
I trying to add bunch of classes, but PhpStorm cannot recognise namespacing and and my classes cannot being auto-imported. 
E.g.
I'm trying to import file `App/Engines/Contracts/BaseEngine.php` which is placed in `src/Engines/Contracts/BaseEngine.php` via
`use App\Engines\Contracts\BaseEngine;`
The PhpStorm says `Undefined Class`

All PhpStorm configuration seems to be correct: I've specified composer.json and checked auto-import in namespace scope.

So, basically the question is: How to deal with composer autoloader in such a library?

Attaching my composer.json code.

```
{
    "name": "mom/task",
    "description": "Todo",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Foo Bar",
            "email": "foo.mail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

UPD: attaching BaseEngine code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Engines\Contracts;

interface BaseEngine
{
    /**
     * @param int $variable
     * @param int $multiplier
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function compute(int $variable, int $multiplier): int;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add the code from your BaseEngine.php file to the question for further clarity? Have you also run composer dump-autoload to build the autoload file?

Comment: Thanks - looks fine so far. Have you run composer dump-autoload?

Comment: @benjaminhull Sorry didn't answered in previous comment. Yes, I've run composer dump-autoload